# how to stop reading when i find end of line

Tags: c++

i m trying to read from a file and stop when i hit end of line. the thing is, it doesnt seem to work.¯_(ツ)_/¯ any ideas why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char a;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("text.txt");
    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
    myfile>> a;
    if (a=='\n')
    cout << "end of line";

    }
myfile.close();
}
```

text file i read:

[image: text file i read]

Comment: `while (!myfile.eof())` [is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not a problem description. What is it actually doing?

Comment: it does not locate the change of line. never types "end of line"

Comment: How are you running it and **what is it actually doing**?

Comment: 1) why is
while (!myfile.eof()) always wrong? i want to check if i have finished reading my file

Comment: 2) i am running it in code blocks, it returns 0 but it never shows "end of line" as it is supposed to

Comment: 1) Click on the link? It explains why.

Answer (score 1):

Try `while (myfile.get(a))` instead?

```
while (myfile.get(a))
{
    if (a=='\n')
        cout << "end of line";

}
```

Comment: @deW1 the example from the question was about character-by-character read, I assumed there is a reason for it. Sure, there is more than one way to do it, as shown in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Why make things harder than needed. If you want to parse lines, then use `std::getline()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::ifstream myfile("text.txt");

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(myfile, line)) {
        std::cout << "end of line" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using a `for` loop

```
std::ifstream ifs( "file" );
for( char chr = 0; ifs.peek() != '\n'; ifs.get( chr ) ){
    std::cout << chr;
}
ifs.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just rewrite your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char a;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("/Users/sijan/CLionProjects/test2/text.txt",ifstream::in);
    while (myfile.get(a))
    {
        cout<< a;

        if (a=='\n')
            cout << "end of line\n";
    }

    if (myfile.eof())
        cout << "end of file";
    myfile.close();
}
```